# Unwind Segues isn't working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

Xcode 5.1.1

I'm using 2 view controllers. ViewController1 and ViewController 2. I want to do the unwind segue when i tap BACK button in ViewController 1 to go to ViewController 2. So in View Controller2 .h file i type   -(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;   Then in viewController2.m file right above @end i type -(IBAction)returned:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{}.   Then i go to storyboards and from my 2nd viewController i drag the button to green EXIT click returned. In connections inspector i hook up RETURNED to the button in viewController2 to say "touch up inside". Then i do a modal from ViewController2 to ViewController 1. Load the simulator, Tap the button in ViewController 2, takes me to ViewController 1 then I tap BACK button in ViewController 1 and it does NOTHING. The unwind segues doesn't work.

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Throw some print statements to check if the view is recognizing the tap gesture on the button, and if the view is calling `prepareForSegue:` and/or `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:` This will help you more accurately see wherein the problem may lie

Comment: I tried that and XCODE is not showing me any issue. The unwind segue still doesn't work. Are there other ways to perform unwinding segues programatically besides what i stated above?